# Not able perform INSERT INTO Operation using VB .NET because of Space in the Column Name

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, sqlcommand

I am trying to perform `INSERT INTO` Operation using `SqlCommand` in VB .NET. My `DataTable` has one Column with a space in its Name. Due to this column name I am not able to perform INSERT INTO Operation. I am getting an error message stating:

> Incorrect Syntax near Column Name

I don't want to change the column name in the DataTable. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Place the name in [ ]

Comment: Show your code which contains the `INSERT INTO`. Do you use a `SqlDataAdapter` and `adapter.Update(table)`? Does the column in the database also has this space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [table name]. Same thing for columns. Means anything with spaces must be placed inside the braces as mentioned by Tushar

Comment: Thank you so much @Mahesh Malpani. It worked like a charm. You Rock :)

Comment: Wow @TheDProgrammer Actually I have answered that :P

Answer (score 2):

That can be rectified Just place your name in `[]`, If naming is the only issue.